# Button doesn´t rotate libGDX

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx, rotation

I want to rotate a button. Therefore I wrote the following code:

```
public void show () {
        skin2 = new Skin (Gdx.files.internal("SettingsButton.json"));
        button2 = new Button(skin2);
        button2.setPosition(25,1440);
        button2.setSize(120,120);
        button2.setOrigin(button2.getWidth() / 2, button2.getHeight() / 2);
        button2.addAction(Actions.repeat(RepeatAction.FOREVER,
                Actions.sequence(
                        Actions.rotateBy(360, 1), 
                        Actions.rotateTo(0))));
        button2.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                game.setScreen(new SettingsScreen(game));
                super.clicked(event, x, y);
            }
        });

        stage.addActor(button2);
}
```

Unfortunately, the button doesn´t rotate but I don´t know why. **How can I improve my code?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For performance reason most `scene2d.ui` groups have `transform` set to false by default.

For more detail you can check 
 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#rotation-and-scale

You need to enable transform by using `setTransform(..)` method

```
button2.setTransform(true);
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any posibility for setting the velocity of the rotation?

Comment: what do you mean by velocity of rotation ?

Comment: I want to set how many revolutions the button makes in a certain period of time e.g. one revolution in a minute is slowlier than 5 revolutions in a minute. So I want to set that.

Comment: `Actions.sequence(Actions.rotateBy(360, 1))` one rotation in one second by this action, if you want slower rotation increase time in sec.. like one rotation in 10 sec by this `Actions.sequence(Actions.rotateBy(360, 10))`