# Libgdx rotating imagebutton

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I am trying to rotate an imagebutton 90 degrees. When I call `button.setRotation(90)`, It rotates the button but not the image associated with the button. I know the actual button is rotated because I print out true when it is clicked, and it senses clicks where the button should be rotated 90 degrees. Setting the position of the button, however, does move both the button and the image. How do I make sure the image rotates with the button? Thank you!

```
package com.davejones.test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ExtendViewport;


public class Test extends ApplicationAdapter {

Stage stage;
ImageButton button;
ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle imageButtonStyle;
BitmapFont font;
Skin skin;
TextureAtlas textureAtlas;
ExtendViewport viewport;

@Override
public void create () {
    stage = new Stage();
    skin = new Skin();
    viewport = new ExtendViewport(64,48);
    viewport.getCamera().position.set(32, 24, 0);
    textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("image.pack");
    skin.addRegions(textureAtlas);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    font = new BitmapFont();
    imageButtonStyle = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
    imageButtonStyle.imageUp = skin.getDrawable("image");
    button = new ImageButton(imageButtonStyle);
    button.setPosition(100, 100);
    button.setRotation(90);
    stage.addActor(button);
}


@Override
public void render () {
    System.out.println(button.isPressed());
    super.render();
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    stage.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
    font.dispose();
    textureAtlas.dispose();
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button doesn´t rotate libGDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607029/button-doesn%c2%b4t-rotate-libgdx)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your button's transfrom to true:

```
...
button.setTransform(true);
button.setRotation(90);
...
```

From [Libgdx Group docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html#setTransform-boolean-):

> public void setTransform(boolean transform)
>
> When true (the default),
> the Batch is transformed so children are drawn in their parent's
> coordinate system. This has a performance impact because Batch.flush()
> must be done before and after the transform. If the actors in a group
> are not rotated or scaled, then the transform for the group can be set
> to false. In this case, each child's position will be offset by the
> group's position for drawing, causing the children to appear in the
> correct location even though the Batch has not been transformed.

So be aware of possible performance impact, if you draw a lot of Groups with transform set to true.

Comment: Not sure if it would help. **When true (the default)...**. As you can see its true by default.

Comment: it's for the Group class. For ImageButton it's false by default